# Processing AJAX result

Tags: javascript, html

I get the javascript file string from ajax, But I can not use the returned javascript string,
I try some way:

1、

```
tools.get({
                 url:'/public/dist/page.index.min.js',
                 success: function(res) {
                     let blob = new Blob([res])
                     let url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob)
                     let reader  = new FileReader()
                     reader.onload = function(e){
                         let script = document.createElement('script')
                         script.src = e.target.result
                         script.type ='text/javascript'
                         document.body.appendChild(script)
                     }
                     reader.readAsDataURL(blob)
                 }
             })
```

2、`document.write(script_strings)`// the script file is compiled by webpack and when render the code in the page, will throw error. like some html tags

3、`eval(script_strings)`//no use

so Is there any solution to solve the problem..

== added ==
 way 1 and way 3: no use and no throw  errors
way 2, throw errors, but I can not deal it.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kUIYM.png)

Comment: You need to include any errors that you are getting and a more explicit defintion of the problem. What do you want to happen? What is or isnt happening?

Comment: That seems unnecessarily complicated... Why not just create the `<script>` with the JS file directly?

Comment: @Niet the Dark Absol  Because the javascript file is encode in base64 format.. I have to decode it .

Comment: @Craicerjack  The fist way and the third are no use and no errors. The second throw errors, but I don't think it is helpful..   ```Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
    at Object.success (universe.js:345)
    at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onload (universe.js:161)
```

Comment: @str It is my first time to try this.. thank you for your advice.

Comment: @str Assume  that I have decoded the base64 to string, how can I use the javascrit string?

Answer (score -1):

I have solve the problem..

```
        let jscontent = tools.byteToString(tools.base64ToUint8Array(res)) 
        let blob = new Blob([jscontent], { type: "application/javascript;charset=utf-8" })
        let url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob)
        let script = document.createElement('script')
        script.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob)
        script.type ='text/javascript'
        document.body.appendChild(script)
```

and it will load the js content to page.